# How to find the person who rename the project name in GitLab?

Tags: user-interface, gitlab

I renamed the project in GitLab. I thought this action would save in Activity of the project. But this was not saved in project Activity. How could I check the person who renamed the project?

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no option to find that out in CE. In EE however there might be an audit for that.

Comment: @Fairy thank you for your information